# How to set default datetime value to Filament PHP v2 DateTimePicker field?

Tags: laravel, datetimepicker, filamentphp

I would like to set a default datetime value for the Filament DateTimePicker field. My main goal is to set the current datetime as default, because in the datepicker it takes to long to set the time.

This is my field:

```
DateTimePicker::make('my_date')
                    ->label('My date')
                    ->minDate(CarbonImmutable::now()->startOfDay())
                    ->withoutSeconds()
                    ->required(),
```

I've tried already with ->default() function, but it doesn't change anything.

Has anyone a solution for this?

Comment: _"I've tried already with ->default() function"_ - using what exact value? By default, this uses native HTML5 datepicker functionality, according to docs, so that would mean an `<input type="date">`. And default values for those must be set in `yyyy-mm-dd` format, even if the display format might differ.

Comment: @CBroe I tried with this: ->default('2023-09-28 10:15:30') and with a simple date as well ->default('2023-09-28') .

Answer (score 4):

You should try this

```php
use Filament\Resources\Forms\Components\DateTimePicker;
...    
DateTimePicker::make('Created At')
        ->default(now()) // Set the default value to the current datetime
        ->format('Y-m-d H:i:s') // Set the datetime format if needed
```

Comment: hello, how can set default date when page load with pure javascript ?